# PHP include unless on a certain page, then include different

Tags: php, menu, header, include

I have a php site that includes a menu.  There is a section that I do not want to include that menu, but want to include a different one.  I am sure I need an if/else but am struggling.

my index is built like this
html and head
div wrapper 
include header
include page build
include footer

the page build file uses the index template and calls for each pages content.  therefore each page uses the same header and footer. i want to use a second header on a specific section.

so section 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 uses header 1
section 2 uses header 2

Comment: Include some code in your question if you want us to help

Comment: `'site is built (using "page build")'` - It is not so clear what you mean by this...

Comment: This might be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: use if(){...}else{.....}

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

say, you have a file called `menu.php` which you want to include in `index.php` and in that menu you do not want to include a menu/text called `Loggin`. Ok? Now, in `menu.php` you can do like this:

```
<p> Home </p><p> about</p><p> profile</p><p> blog</p><?php if(isset($allow)) {echo '<p> Loggin</p>';} else {echo "";}
```

With the above `if/else` you are telling PHP, if the variable $allow has any value echo Loggin, else show nothing. now all you have to do, is include your menu, but in index.php either set $value to anything if you want Loggin to be shown, or just leave it if you don't want loggin to not appear

Answer (score -1):

You could try using:

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/page1.php") {
    include("fileToInclude.php");
} else {
    include("differentFileToInclude.php");
}
```